# Como converter AnsiString para Char no C++ Builder?

Tags: c, c++, string, c++-builder

Preciso escolher um arquivo `txt` através do `OpenDialog`, para abrir através de `fopen`. O problema que estou encontrado e na conversão. A função `fopen` tem como parâmetro uma `const char`, já `opendialog` devolve o caminho do arquivo como uma `ansistring` (segue o código)

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 AnsiString Arquivo;

 FILE *Fin;

 if(OpenDialog1->Execute())
   Arquivo = OpenDialog1->FileName;
 Fin = fopen(Arquivo,"rt") ;
 Button1->Enabled = true;
}
//-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `c_str()` converte o texto para `const char *`, então basta usar `Arquivo.c_str()`.